# VB6 to C++/CLI wrapper around managed C# method

Tags: c#, vb6, c++-cli

There is a ton of great info on SO and on the net (pinvoke.net for example) that describes calling unmanaged code from managed code. I am in an unique situation where I need to implement an API for a legacy VB6 app which can not be changed for business reasons. For the sake of brevity, lets say the VB6 app does the following.

```
'Legacy VB6
Public Declare Function GetData Lib "NewDLL" (ByVal szDataID As String, 
ByRef DataStruct As TDataStruct) As Long

Type TDataStruct
    szSKU       As String * 10
    szTypeInfo  As String * 20
End Type
```

Here is how I approached it.

C++/CLI implementation.

```
//NewDLL.h
typedef struct DATASTRUCT
{
   char szSKU      [10];
   char szTypeInfo [20];
];

//NewDLL.cpp - C++/CLI
#include "NewDLL.h"
using namespace System;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
Int32 __stdcall GetData(LPTSTR szDataID, DATASTRUCT* dataStruct)
{
   String^ m_DataID;

   m_DataID = gcnew String(szDataID);

   NewDotNetDll::GetDataClass::GetData(m_DataID, dataStruct);
   return (true);
}
```

.NET implementation.

```
//DataStruct.cs
using etc...
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace NewDotNetDll
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct DataStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
        public string SkuID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        public string TypeInfo;
    }
}

//GetDataClass.cs
using etc...
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NewDotNetDll
{
    public class GetDataClass
    {
        public static Int32 GetData(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string skuID,
            [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DataStruct dataStruct)
        {
            Int32 rc = 0;
            //to do...
            return rc;
        }
     }
}
```

Question - how can I pass the VB's TDataStruct to my C# method by reference so that it can act on the in-memory, unmanaged struct? Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map a struct to existing unmanaged memory, it cannot contain managed types (object references or structs which do not satisfy the same condition).

`string` is a managed type, and it contains UTF-16 characters. Your data structure contains 8-bit C++ `char`s. So it's unsuitable.

`byte[]` is *also* a managed type, since an array is actually a reference to an object in C#. So you can't use that either.

Let's handle that by using [fixed-size buffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public unsafe struct DataStruct
{
    public fixed byte SkuID[10];
    public fixed byte TypeInfo[20];
}
```

And now we can declare a pointer to the struct in C#:

```
public unsafe static Int32 GetData(string skuID, DataStruct *dataStruct)
{
    dataStruct->SkuID[0] = 65;
    dataStruct->SkuID[1] = 0;
    return 42;
}
```

And there's no need to use `MarshalAsAttribute` at this point.

Here's an example of string handling (copying `skuID` to `dataStruct->SkuID`):

```
public unsafe static Int32 GetData(string skuID, DataStruct *dataStruct)
{
    var skuIdBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(skuID);
    if (skuIdBytes.Length >= 10)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(skuID), "skuID is too long");

    Marshal.Copy(skuIdBytes, 0, new IntPtr(dataStruct->SkuID), skuIdBytes.Length);
    dataStruct->SkuID[skuIdBytes.Length + 1] = 0;

    return 42;
}
```

Comment: Lucas, thank you so much. I am still running into a minor issue - error C2664 cannot convert argument 2 from 'DATASTRUCT *' to 'NewDotNetDll::DataStruct *' when I build my C++/CLIP wrapper. My managed DataStruct has been modified per your suggestion - it contains no managed types.

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that. You'll have to cast: `reinterpret_cast<NewDotNetDll::DataStruct*>(dataStruct)` should do the trick (as the types are unrelated as far as the compiler can tell).